# how does spring boot auto configure the driver of a special datasource?

Tags: spring-boot, datasource

Without spring boot ,we must specify the detail of a data source,right?

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

With spring boot,we even do not need do anything,I know spring boot will detect whether there is a jar contains a data source to decide create a data source bean or not.I see the source code from `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration` :

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Conditional(PooledDataSourceCondition.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ DataSource.class, XADataSource.class })
@Import({ DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari.class, DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat.class,
        DataSourceConfiguration.Dbcp2.class, DataSourceConfiguration.OracleUcp.class,
        DataSourceConfiguration.Generic.class, DataSourceJmxConfiguration.class })
protected static class PooledDataSourceConfiguration {

}
```

But my question is how does spring boot know the driver class or url and else for every different database?I can not find any specification from `spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [DataSource Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.sql.datasource.configuration) in the docs:

> Spring Boot can deduce the JDBC driver class for most databases from the URL. If you need to specify a specific class, you can use the `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property.

So start without configuring anything and just putting the JDBC driver on the classpath. If it would not work, you can manually configure it.

Comment: is there any source code of spring boot to show how it does?